# Regex select data within quotations

Tags: c#, .net, regex, selection

I have a string: `"var1=\"Some Data\";var2=\"More Data\"` and I would like to select the data within the quotes as well as the data to the left of it(the variable name).

For example:

`"var1" = "Some Data",
 "var2" = "More Data"`

The commands are semi-colon delimited and the variable's value is always contained within quotations. However the variables are based on user input and may also contain other quotations or semi-colons. I have attempted to do this with Split and Substring however they were affected by the user input. How would I do this without it being affected by the user input ?

Edit:
I didn't think to mention that I already have an expression that selects data within the quotes. However I'm not familiar enough with Regex to make it select the variable name too. The current Regex expression is: `(\".*\")`

Comment: If there are other quotations in the user input, are they escaped? Does the user then also have to escape the escape char?

Comment: @Michelle the quotations would be escaped.

Comment: @umbreon222 that question doesn't address the possibility of the input containing the delimiter.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your unsuccessful regular expressions which we could help you debug?

Comment: @umbreon222 I have just checked that link, and that is used to replace, and does not help me fetch the variable name assigned to it(on the left). But thanks regardless.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am able to grab the data within the quotes, I should've specified that in my post. the main problem is I can't select the data to the left(the variable name).

Comment: @Brodie Please show us the regular expression that works on the quoted value but fails to retrieve the variable name. We can help you understand what's wrong with it. I can't guess what's wrong with it without seeing it. On SO, you need to show people the code that's not working.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have edited my post. You should now see the extra info.

Comment: @Brodie [Start here](http://regexone.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex I decided to use was: `;(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`. That selects the entire command ( `variableName="Hello World"` ) and then use Substring to select the data before and after the equals. I then use trim to remove the quotes. It works perfectly, and I am able to use quotations that are escaped within the main quotations.

I take no credit for that Regex command. I found it on the web somewhere(I will post it here when I remember where).

Thanks for all the answers and links anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you're after:

```
"(.+)"\s?=\s?"(.+)"
```

example: [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=b0bd7ed5-b2af-486a-8dae-4984185aa103)

Regex quantifiers `+` and `*` are greedy by default and will look for the longest match.

You can add additional test cases with more or no white space between the quoted strings and `=` to make sure that it will satisfy your needs.

**Edit:** This will not work for multiple instances on the same line, as it relies on the greediness of the quantifiers.